# Alternatives to SQLite in VS2013 with EF6 and designer support

Tags: entity-framework, sqlite, visual-studio-2013

I have previously used System.Data.Sqlite 1.0.85 with EF5 in VS2010 and it worked well and I came to really like the designer. On my new machine, I've switched to VS2013 Community and tried to get Sqlite 1.0.94 and EF6 running, but it's such a hassle and I'm starting to get really frustrated. I can't seem to get it running on my old project, which I need to work on, but only on a fresh one. Tried copying the old stuff, but it just stops working again. From what I've read, I'm not the only one having these issues.

I can connect to the database in the server explorer, but the connection won't show up in the Entity Data Model wizard. It did run once on a fresh project, but since I keep running into trouble, I'd rather switch to something else that actually works.

So my question is, what alternatives are there? It's for a small business application. Would LocalDb be an alternative? Are there any other good databases/providers (free ones) that work well with EF and have designer support in VS2013?

Thanks for any feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LocalDb can be used in the dev environment and works really well. But it might be too limiting for production use depending upon your requirements. Another option would be to use SQL Server Express. But this again might have limitations in a prod environment. The following link gives you an overview of the features of different versions of SQL Server:

[SQL Server Editions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx)

Another option would be to go for something like PostgresSQL or MySQL but I haven't used them, so can't say much about them.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll probably try LocalDb first, if I can find an easy way to convert my SQLite database. Do you have any suggestions? Changing to something like SQL Server down the road is probably inevitable, even if SQLite would be working right now, so it's probably not a bad thing to get this done now.

Comment: I haven't worked with SQLite but using LocalDb is straight forward. It just works. And switching to SQL Server whenever you are ready would also be painless.

Comment: Use the SQLite Toolbox add-in to convert from SQLite to SQL Server

Comment: Thanks, ErikEJ. Could you explain to me, how I convert from one to the other? I can't seem to find the option.